# Guard let not distinguishing inputs

Tags: swift

I have a SIMPLE login screen and I am protecting against missing data as follows:

```
@IBAction func btnLoginTapped(_ sender: Any)
    {
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty else
        {
            self.showMessage(messageToDisplay: "Email Address is required", title: "")
            return
        }

        guard let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty else
        {
            self.showMessage(messageToDisplay: "Password is required", title: "")
            return
        }
....
```

I load the app on my device and press login and get the alert "Email Address is required". I enter my email address and press login and get the alert "Email Address is required" and NOT "Password is required"

How can that be???

Comment: You would need to use breakpoints and check the value of email the second time around and see what it is set to. one of those conditions must be returning false or there is something wrong with showMessage function

Comment: breakpoints showed that both outlets pointed to the same damn textfield ... stupid me!

Comment: yep I suspected something like that; I believe my answer covers that likelihood :)

Comment: it happens to the best of us, good luck with the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a problem with the *first* `guard let`, we print "Email Address is required" *and return*.

Thus, the *second* `guard let` is never encountered and "Password is required" is never printed.

Your code will *never* print *both* messages; that would be impossible, the way you've written the code.

So we have to conclude that one of the tests in the first `guard let` is failing. But you have not given enough information for us to know why that is. Perhaps `emailTextField` is `nil`? Perhaps `showMessage` doesn't do what you think it does? You could be making a *lot* of wrong assumptions here. But the *logic* of your code is clear.

Comment: that's understandable ... but when I tap login the second time, I have an email address, so I would think the first let would be by-passed

Comment: Okay but that would be outside the scope of the info you've given. Clearly the first `guard let` is firing. Maybe `emailTextField` outlet is not hooked up? Impossible to know from here; you have to look and figure it out.